# Leader-follower-leader games

Tags: game-theory, reference-request, definition

I am trying to find some literature on a variation of a Stackelberg game in which two players, P1 and P2, interact in the following order:

1. P1 plays
2. P2 plays
3. P1 plays

The best guess I have for the name of this sort of game, inspired by the "leader-follower" setting of a Stackelberg game, is "leader-follower-leader" but that's not giving me many useful results.

**Question:** Does anyone know if such a game has a name or has been studied?

Comment: I think these types of game cover a lot of dynamic games. In fact I am not sure how this game would require a different set of assumptions or solution method from standard leader-follower games. You may want to assume perfect recall, but that is about it.

Comment: You do not need any such game to be studied in the past, you only need a precise definition of the type od game that you want to adjust. Then just implemnt your idea, but the Stackelberg is a leader follower game, which means that some player moves first by forcasting the strategy of her competitor if he makes a or some action and then he uses the backward induction to solve her initila problem...

Comment: Contrarily, If the leader-follower-leader does not account in what you have to do, just stop thinking to use a specific type of game. Namely, create your type of stage game based on the best response problem and then you can see if this is a Stackelberg or maybe it is not,...So it is a game after all and it does not need to be some specific one! Remember, that you may need to use a fixed point theorem solution in some cases...

Comment: @Giskard Thanks for the comment. By a similar solution method, do you mean that I can likely approach this game by looking at compositions of strategies similar to a standard Stackelberg setting?

Comment: @jonem I mean backward induction.

Comment: In terms of the theory needed to solve a "leader-follower-leader" game, it is essentially the same that you need for the "leader-follower" game. This is why you don't find papers addressing it specifically, though surely many interesting applications can come from adding a third period, there is no need to give it a unique name or write a paper about it.  As @Giskard said, so long as there is perfect recall, the most accepted way to solve these games is using sub-game perfect Nash Equilibrium (or Backward induction). The famous bargaining model with a finite number of periods is a good example